# data-toggle="collapse" does not collapse my data when clicked

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have run into an interesting dilemma. I am trying to create a collapsible div to hold my data, and thus far it does not work. I thought it might be the jquery that is giving me my nightmare but after referencing it to google I still get the same problem. Once I click to collapse/expand. It does not do anything. Can you guys see anything wrong ?

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" style="margin-top: 15px">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Complete Database Export</a>
                <small style="margin-left: 10px">(click here)</small>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="row" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="label">Complete Database Export</asp:Label>
                    <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p class="fg-color-grey">Enter the email addresses where the report will be sent to, seperated by commas:</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDumpEmails" runat="server" CssClass="genericTextBox widthOverride"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnDump" runat="server" Text="Generate Complete Database Export" CssClass="simpleButton marginOverride" OnClick="btnDatabaseDump_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Is there anything I can try to check or that I have forgotten ?
Thanks in advance. I am really frustrated with this at the moment.

***EDIT***

I should also note that I do not get any errors in the web inspector console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the code that you have will do the collapse/expand but it is on the link i.e.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Complete Database Export</a>
```

and not on the following code:

```
<small style="margin-left: 10px">(click here)</small>
```

**Expanded screen shot**

[image: Expanded]

**Collapsed screen shot**

[image: Collapsed]

If by selecting the *'Complete Database Export'* link it is not exanding/collapsing you need to check that all your bootstrap resource files are loading correctly.

I would guess at the js file being missing which you could test by referencing the cdn  i.e.

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```